# C# - Making a class thread safe

Tags: c#, thread-safety

I have been given the following code and tasked with making it thread safe:

```
public class HashtableWrapper
{

    private Hashtable _cachedData;

    public HashtableWrapper()
    {
        _cachedData = new Hashtable();
    }

    public void Add(object key, object value)
    {
        _cachedData[key] = value;
    }

    public object Get(object key)
    {
        return _cachedData[key];
    }
}
```

I am not that well versed in threading but the following is some 'solutions' I have found/come up with:

- Would it have something to do with making the Add and Get methods synchronised?
- Making `_cachedData` static?
- Creating a synchronised wrapper around Hashtable: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.hashtable.synchronized?view=netcore-3.1 (Unsure where to do this if this was the solution - after `_cachedData = new Hashtable();` maybe?)
- Using a lock object, like here: [Making class fields thread-safe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32197354/making-class-fields-thread-safe) - for example:

  ```
  private static object lockObject = new Object();

  public void Add(object key, object value)
    {
        lock(lockObject)
        {
            _cachedData[key] = value;
        }
    }
  ```

Comment: All you need is here (or in others online tutorials and printed books): [Threading in C#, by Joe Albahari](http://www.albahari.com/threading). And here: [Thread-Safe Collections](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/standard/collections/thread-safe/)

Comment: If you are not well-versed in threading, don't make your own thread-safe collections or wrappers.  If you MUST use a Hashtable, use the Synchronized wrapper, or, better yet, use a ConcurrentDictionary.

Comment: Here is an example: [ConcurrentQueue.cs](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/Collections/Concurrent/ConcurrentQueue.cs,3aca362f2b1eb019)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is Hashtable.Synchronized suitable for use as a simple cache in a multithreaded environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12554803/is-hashtable-synchronized-suitable-for-use-as-a-simple-cache-in-a-multithreaded) and [Minimal-locking thread-safe hashtable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2111030/minimal-locking-thread-safe-hashtable) and [Thread-safe HashTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15729614/thread-safe-hashtable) and [How to make a class Thread Safe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1344025/how-to-make-a-class-thread-safe)

Comment: @OlivierRogier Thanks, I'll take a look at all these